# How to set JVM memory for a specific web application

Tags: memory, jvm, heap-memory

I'm a little confused about the JVM memory management.

1) When running my web application on Eclipse, I know that I can edit the **eclipse.ini** and modify **Xms** and **Xmx** paramethers.
The memory changes will affect all the web applications I run on Eclipse? Is it correct?

2)How can I set the memory size for a specific web application, in order to be sure that a specific web application running under a server (tomcat, weblogic, etc.) will have that memory?

I see many examples with this command **java -Xms16m -Xmx64m ClassName**, but I can't understand what should be the ClassName value for a web application.

Thank you guys

Comment: Web Servers have their own startup scripts and configuration files for setting the heap size. I suggest you have a look at the docs for your web server, or you could read the startup scripts you use to run your server.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you, I'll follow your advice.

Comment: You can view the following thread of how it was done on tomcat 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106789/how-to-increase-tomcat-heap-memory-on-windows/54109136#54109136

Comment: Did it solve the issue ?

Comment: Yes, the link you posted was a thread of mine. I solved the problem following the direction of @Đức Trần Trung